# Styling form IE9 with border-radius

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css

I have a problem with the styling of a searchbar in IE9. There is a white block behind the input and submit button, but can't take it away with css.

My css code for that block:

```
.searchfield{

position:relative;
margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:20px;
height: 90px;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-radius: 25px;
border-radius: 25px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000000;

background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 50%, #e1e1e1 51%, #f6f6f6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(50%,#f1f1f1), color-stop(51%,#e1e1e1), color-stop(100%,#f6f6f6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f1f1f1 50%,#e1e1e1 51%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

}

But the strangest is that the border-radius is working well, check the shadows in the picture[image: .]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Already tried that, but no luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem with the use of data uri encoding from a background image.

Nevertheless, thanks for helping!